# Converting x//y into x/y" Excel

Tags: regex, excel, excel-2007, wildcard, vba

I'm looking for a solution to convert a text stored in an Excel cell from,

```
x//y
```

into

```
x/y"
```

(preferably using serach and replace if possible)

Values of **x** & **y** will keep changing from cell to cell however pattern will be the same.
I am using Excel 2007. A VBA solution if any will be fine also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No VBA Required. Try this Excel formula

`=MID(A1,1,FIND("//",A1,1)-1)&"/"&MID(A1,FIND("//",A1,1)+2,LEN(A1)-FIND("//",A1,1)-1)&""""`

**Explanation**

1. `=MID(A1,1,FIND("//",A1,1)-1)` will give you `X` from `X//Y`
2. `=MID(A1,FIND("//",A1,1)+2,LEN(A1)-FIND("//",A1,1)-1)` will give you `Y`

Comment: Raghu's formula is much better. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes tried, I've got an error in first attempt in Raghu's formula(don't know why, I'm not really that great in Excel). However now that formula is working too. Thanks again to all of you for quick solutions.

Comment: It worked for me :) Simply replace `C2` with the cell which has the x//y text

Answer (score 5):

Try =CONCATENATE(SUBSTITUTE(C2,"//","/",1),"""")

Something like above works?

Answer (score 0):

Use next pattern of RegEx for replacing `//`

`\/\/(\w+)`

with `/$1"`